# Opening Terminal shows a list of ttys - unable to use

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

Having the latest Mavericks installed, I tried to update `PATH` using nano and creating a `.bash_profile` file. I'm not sure what happened, but now when trying to run Terminal all that shows is a list of `ttys000` messages followed by a `wtmp begins` message.

And finally says:

```
-bash:<computername>:~: command not found

[Process completed]
```

I've downloaded a program to find hidden files but there's no sign of the `.bash_profile` file.

Any ideas how to rescue the Terminal program?

Comment: Hours of searching, posted this question, found out what to do almost immediately.....as per this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081058/cant-use-terminal-from-error-in-bash-profile

Comment: Well, that's fairly common. No worries. You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Bash with all startup scripts disabled to get around problems with startup scripts: choose **Shell > New Command** and run `bash --noprofile`.

See the Bash man page for more information about the Bash command-line options and startup files: x-man-page://1/bash

Also note that you can lookup and view man pages in Terminal even when your shell isn't working, by clicking on the Help menu and entering a topic in the search field. Terminal will display matching man pages. Choose one from the Help menu to view it in a new window. You can also open an `x-man-page:` scheme URL from any application.